# Remove stopwords from sentences

Tags: python, string, split

I'd want to remove stopwords from a sentence.
I've this piece of code:

```
splitted = text.split()

for index, word in enumerate(splitted):
    if word in self.stopWords:
        del splitted[index]

text = " ".join(splitted)
```

stopWords is updated with this instruction `self.stopWords.update(['.', ',', "\"", "\'", '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '),', '],', '},', '",', "',", '")', '"]', '"}', "-", "--", '\".', "\'.", '/', ').', '-', '--', '%', '°\'', '(-', '("', '."', '.),', ');', '–', '$', 'a'])` but, for example, the letter 'a', such as '.', or ';' isn't deleted from the sentence.

What would I do?

Comment: don't delete from a list while iterating through it. Create a new one instead while filtering

Comment: Your `self.stopWords` contains **Character** instead of **Words**, think about the difference between both

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier to use list comprehension (or generator expression as I do here):

```
' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in stop_words)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try my code? If you have any question about code,just ask to me.

```
def splitFile(lines,splitvalue):
    documents={};
    documentCount=1
    dcmnt="";
    for line in lines:
        dcmnt+=line;
        if (line.__contains__(splitvalue)):
            key="documents"+(str)(documentCount);
            documents[key]=dcmnt;
            dcmnt="";
            documentCount=documentCount+1;
    return documents;

documentswords = []
with open('reuter10.txt','r') as f:  #reading a text file and splitting it into single words
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            documentswords.append(word)
stopwords=[]
with open('stopwords.txt','r') as f:  #reading a text file and splitting it into single words
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            stopwords.append(word)

readFile=open("reuter10.txt","r");
lines=readFile.readlines();
readFile.close();
alldocuments=splitFile(lines, "</reuters>");
temp=[]

for i in range(0,documentswords.__len__()):
    count = 0;
    for ii in range(0, stopwords.__len__()):
        if documentswords[i]==stopwords[ii]:
            count=count+1
        if ii+1==stopwords.__len__() and count==0:
            temp.append(documentswords[i])
print("")
print("*****PRINTING WORDS WITHOUT STOPWORDS*****")
print("")
for i in range(0, temp.__len__()): #printing words without stopwords
    print(temp[i]);
```